# Django - check if object exists

Tags: django

I'm trying to check if an object exists in my form but i'm getting an error.

**my views:**

```
def foo(request):
    titulo = "something"
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    queryset = myModel.objects.all()
    if myModel.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
        messages.error(request, 'already exists')
    context = {
        "titulo": titulo,
        "form": form,
        "queryset": queryset,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Added')
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, "forms7.html", context)
```

Basically what I'm doing is adding an user, if the user exists I want a warning saying `already exists`

Error:

> UnboundLocalError at /model/ local variable 'name'
>   referenced before assignment

What am I doing wrong?

**Note:**
If I add `name = 'jesus'` to my code and `jesus` exists it works but that's not how I want.

I want to check if the name I'm entering exists show me the msg

Could someone help me? thanks.

Comment: Where is the variable `name` coming from?

Answer (score 5):

When using forms, you get an inputted form field by calling `is_valid` and then accessing `cleaned_data`, like this:

```
def foo(request):
    titulo = "something"
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    queryset = myModel.objects.all()
    context = {
        "titulo": titulo,
        "form": form,
        "queryset": queryset,
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        if myModel.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'already exists')
        else:                
            instance = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Added')
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request, "forms7.html", context)
```

Ideally, you’d have a `clean_name` function in your form so that your view is less complicated.  You can read more about creating such a method [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/).

> For example, if you wanted to validate that the contents of a CharField
>   called serialnumber was unique, clean_serialnumber() would be the right
>   place to do this. You don’t need a specific field (it’s just a
>   CharField), but you want a formfield-specific piece of validation and,
>   possibly, cleaning/normalizing the data.

e.g., you might want something like:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form)
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if myModel.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('The name [%s] already exists' % name)    
        return name
```

Comment: raise new forms.ValidationError('The name [%s] already exists' % name) , the word new is a typo

Comment: Thanks for the assist @sibish!