# remove an element from select once added to the db (filtering)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

post code and photos because I don't know how to explain the problem.
I have this green button that opens a modal which allows me to create a group and save it in the db once clicked on add group. After adding the object in the db I reload the page with the data entered via modal, if I click again on the green button I have the possibility to add another object. The problem that I can always add the same object in the select, I wish that once added there is no longer the possibility to add it.

[image: example]

form

```
class EserciziForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.DatiEsercizi
        exclude = ['gruppo_single']
    
class GruppiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.DatiGruppi
    exclude = ['gruppi_scheda']
```

html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}

  <section class="container mt-3">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <h1 class="nome-scheda">CREA</h1>
      <a href="{% url 'lista-gruppi' %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">LISTA</a>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="scheda mb-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <h4 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Nome: {{ scheda.nome_scheda }}</h4>
        <div>
          <p style="margin-bottom: 0;">
            <span><strong>Inizio: {{ scheda.data_inizio }}</strong></span> |
            <span><strong>Fine: {{ scheda.data_fine }}</strong></span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      {% for gruppo in scheda.gruppi_scheda.all %}
        <div class="gruppo mb-3">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0;">{{ gruppo.dati_gruppo.nome_gruppo }}</p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0;">{{ gruppo.giorni_settimana }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}

      <div class="text-end">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#gruppo">Aggiungi gruppo</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="gruppo" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="gruppoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="gruppoLabel">Aggiungi gruppo</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="gruppo mb-3">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    {{ gruppo_form.giorni_settimana.label_tag }}
                    {{ gruppo_form.giorni_settimana }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    {{ gruppo_form.dati_gruppo.label_tag }}
                    {{ gruppo_form.dati_gruppo }}
                  </div>
                  
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-end">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Aggiungi gruppo</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

view

```
def creazione(request, nome):
    scheda = get_object_or_404(Schede, nome_scheda = nome)
    if request.method == "POST":
        gruppo_form = GruppiForm(request.POST, prefix = 'gruppo')
        if gruppo_form.is_valid():
            gruppo = gruppo_form.save(commit = False)
            gruppo.gruppi_scheda = scheda
            gruppo.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    else:
        gruppo_form = GruppiForm(prefix = 'gruppo')

    context = {'scheda' : scheda, 'gruppo_form' : gruppo_form}
    return render(request, 'crea/passo2.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem that I can always add the same object in the select, I wish that once added there is no longer the possibility to add it.

If the problem is rooted to not having the saved data displayed again in the modal, then you would need to make sure that the saved data is not passed to the template from `views.py`.

An easier solution would be to modify your method in `views.py`, such that when a data is submitted it is taken out of the `gruppo_form`. This way it will remove the saved data and will not display as required. You can also check the form objects to see if that data already exists, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374782/django-check-if-object-exists), if so then do not return that to the template.

Comment: and how can I delete them from the form?

Comment: @riccardotest Can you not use filters for this? Django filters, so you filter out that value just within the select and you have access to it outside.

Comment: not being very practical and still being a beginner I would need an example, and on that link I can't find the solution to my problem

Comment: @riccardotest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090735/register-custom-filter-in-django) is an example of filtering in Django template. If not clear, I would suggest looking up the django docs for this. Once you understand how they work, you will be able to filter out the values